# How print a part of string in C

Tags: c, string, character

I would like to print a part of string. My program should print characters from begin until in string will be for example character like this: \"

For example:

```
char* text = "abcdef\"ghij";
```

And I would like to get: `abcdef`

I am not experienced in C so please help me in clear way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `*` field width to select the number of characters to print:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* text = "abcdef\"ghij";
printf("%.*s\n", (int) (strchr(text, '"') - text), text);
```

Comment: it's not a good way, because I don't know in which place in order will be that character. I only give an example. It must be universal

Answer (score 3):

Print char by char in a loop until either the stop character occurs or the current character becomes falsy, i.e. is the null terminator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* text = "abcdef\"ghij";
char stop = '"';

for (char *i = text; *i && *i != stop; i++)
    putc(*i, stdout);
```

Comment: `printf("%c"`?? Why not `fputc`?!

Comment: You're right, strictly speaking it works so I've undone my downvote.  But you have a huge overhead of calling printf(), let this function interpret its command string, and pass over to os, for each single char of the string.  And it does work only for fixed sized strings.

Comment: Calling strlen on every iteration of the loop is bad practice.

Comment: As strlen() counts the number of chars until he reaches char 0, you could further improve your loop look by combining the two iterations: for (int i=0; text[i] && text[i]!='\"'; i++) putchar(text[i]);

Comment: @Christophe I applied your improvements. Do you really have to escape the `"` when its in single quotes?

Comment: @danijar you're right: both forms are acceptable within single quote.  I'm old, that's why I tend to keep my habits ;-). If you look for further improvements, you could either start using pointers instead of text and i, or make a grouped output using fwrite().